# Installing openjdk in docker removes basic linux commands

Tags: java, docker

I aim to make a docker image that contains qt-android and android-studio tool. I took like base for dockerfile [this one](https://hub.docker.com/r/picoded/ubuntu-openjdk-8-jdk/~/dockerfile/), and, instead of installing `software-properties-common`, I've put to install `build-essential` and `libgl1­-mesa­-dev`. Both Java and theses libraries were installed with success, but, then, basic commands like `mkdir`, `ls`, `cd` turned to be unrecognizable, making docker build process return with code 127 (command not found).

Why does this occurs?

Comment: Can you show your would Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1):

I found that I couldn't even get your Dockerfile to display the issue without making some changes earlier in the image. The bit that was actually your problem though is:

```
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
ENV PATH JAVA_HOME/bin
ENV CLASSPATH JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
ENV MANPATH JAVA_HOME/man
RUN export JAVA_HOME PATH CLASSPATH MANPATH
```

Should become:

```
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
ENV PATH $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
ENV CLASSPATH $JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
ENV MANPATH $JAVA_HOME/man
```

This is because when you set the PATH you shouldn't remove the current contents of it (hence `$PATH:`) and you want to add the value of the JAVA_HOME variable rather than the literal string JAVA_HOME (hence `$JAVA_HOME/bin`).

Also, anything you set with ENV you will not need to export as it will be available for every process in your image.

I also had to install some packages to make add-apt-repository available but I'm not 100% sure if this is because ubuntu:latest refers to a different image on my system (possibly you should consider using a tag for the specific version you wish to use like `ubuntu:xenial`).

I also had to install wget & I corrected a number of places where you were using `wget -O -` where you didn't mean to (as you clearly wanted to write the files to disk).

The full Dockerfile which I used & was able to get to successfully build (I didn't test running it as I'm not sure on expected behaviour & don't speak your language) is:

```
 # BASED ON : https://hub.docker.com/r/picoded/ubuntu-openjdk-8-jdk/~/dockerfile/

FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER Inacio Medeiros <inaciogmedeiros@gmail.com>
USER root

# Install the python script required for "add-apt-repository"
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install build-essential libgl1-mesa-dev -y --force-yes

# Sets language to UTF8 : this works in pretty much all cases
ENV LANG pt_BR.UTF-8
RUN locale-gen $LANG

# Install add-apt-repository
RUN apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties wget -y --force-yes

# INSTALL JAVA
# ==============================================================
# Setup the openjdk 8 repo
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa

# Install java8
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk -y --force-yes

# Setup JAVA_HOME and other environment variables, this is useful for docker commandline
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
ENV PATH $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
ENV CLASSPATH $JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
ENV MANPATH $JAVA_HOME/man
# ==============================================================

# Install QT Android
# ==============================================================
RUN mkdir /var/tmp/qt-android \
      && cd /var/tmp/qt-android \
      && wget "http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.5/5.5.0/qt-opensource-linux-x64-android-5.5.0-2.run" \
      && chmod 777 qt-opensource-linux-x64-android-5.5.0-2.run

CMD /var/tmp/qt-android/qt-opensource-linux-x64-android-5.5.0-2.run

RUN cd /var/tmp/qt-android \
      && cd .. \
      && rm -rf /var/tmp/qt-android
# ==============================================================

# Install Ant
RUN apt-get install ant -y --force-yes

# Install SDK
RUN mkdir /opt/android-sdk \
      && cd /opt/android-sdk \
      && wget -O - "http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.3.4-linux.tgz" \
      | tar --strip-components=1 -zxf -

#Install NDK
RUN mkdir /var/tmp/ndk \
      && cd /var/tmp/ndk \
      && wget "http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r10e-linux-x86_64.bin" \
      && chmod 777 android-ndk-r10e-linux-x86_64.bin

CMD /var/tmp/ndk/android-ndk-r10e-linux-x86_64.bin

RUN cd /var/tmp/ndk \
      && cd .. \
      && rm -rf ndk

# Run SDK Update
RUN cd /opt/android-sdk/tools \
       && chmod 777 android

CMD /opt/android-sdk/tools/android update sdk

# Update libraries
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y --force-yes

# Install libraries
RUN apt-get install -y --force-yes libstdc++6 libgcc1 zlib1g libncurses5
RUN apt-get install -y --force-yes libsdl1.2debian

# Install Android studio
# Source: https://github.com/wolfitem/docker/blob/master/Dockerfiles/android-studio/Dockerfile
RUN apt-get install unzip -y --force-yes
RUN wget 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/2.1.0.9/android-studio-ide-143.2790544-linux.zip' -O /tmp/studio.zip && unzip -d /opt /tmp/studio.zip && rm /tmp/studio.zip


#clean up
RUN apt-get clean
RUN apt-get purge

USER developer

CMD /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
```

The thing which I did notice is there are a number of places where you do something like `CMD /var/tmp/qt-android/qt-opensource-linux-x64-android-5.5.0-2.run` where it looks like you are wanting to run `/var/tmp/qt-android/qt-opensource-linux-x64-android-5.5.0-2.run`. I think you have possibly misunderstood what CMD does - it doesn't actually run that command, it sets it up so that when you run a container from the image with `docker run` that will be the default command.

If I had to refactor the Dockerfile I would make it look more like the one below. But this currently fails to build because I changed it to actually call the things mentioned above. Currently `qt-opensource-linux-x64-android-5.5.0-2.run` fails because it can't find a display to connect to.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER Inacio Medeiros <inaciogmedeiros@gmail.com>

# Install the python script required for "add-apt-repository"
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --force-yes \
        build-essential \
        libgl1-mesa-dev \
        python-software-properties \
        software-properties-common \
        wget \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Sets language to UTF8 : this works in pretty much all cases
ENV LANG pt_BR.UTF-8
RUN locale-gen $LANG

# INSTALL JAVA
# ==============================================================
# Setup the openjdk 8 repo
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa

# Install java8
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --force-yes \
        openjdk-8-jdk \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Setup JAVA_HOME and other environment variables, this is useful for docker commandline
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
ENV PATH $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
ENV CLASSPATH $JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
ENV MANPATH $JAVA_HOME/man
# ==============================================================

# Install QT Android
# ==============================================================
RUN mkdir -p /var/tmp/qt-android \
    && cd /var/tmp/qt-android \
    && wget "http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.5/5.5.0/qt-opensource-linux-x64-android-5.5.0-2.run" \
    && chmod 777 qt-opensource-linux-x64-android-5.5.0-2.run \
    && /var/tmp/qt-android/qt-opensource-linux-x64-android-5.5.0-2.run \
    && cd / \
    && rm -rf /var/tmp/qt-android
# ==============================================================

# Install Ant
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --force-yes \
        ant \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Install SDK
RUN mkdir -p /opt/android-sdk \
    && cd /opt/android-sdk \
    && wget -O - "http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.3.4-linux.tgz" \
        | tar --strip-components=1 -zxf -

#Install NDK
RUN mkdir /var/tmp/ndk \
      && cd /var/tmp/ndk \
      && wget "http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r10e-linux-x86_64.bin" \
      && chmod 777 android-ndk-r10e-linux-x86_64.bin \
      && /var/tmp/ndk/android-ndk-r10e-linux-x86_64.bin \
      && cd / \
      && rm -rf /var/tmp/ndk

# Run SDK Update
RUN cd /opt/android-sdk/tools \
    && chmod 777 android \
    && /opt/android-sdk/tools/android update sdk

# Update libraries
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get upgrade -y --force-yes \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Install libraries
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt­-get install -y --force-yes \
        libstdc++6 \
        libgcc1 \
        libsdl1.2debian \
        zlib1g \
        libncurses5 \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Install Android studio
# Source: https://github.com/wolfitem/docker/blob/master/Dockerfiles/android-studio/Dockerfile
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --force-yes \
        unzip \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN wget 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/2.1.0.9/android-studio-ide-143.2790544-linux.zip' -O /tmp/studio.zip \
    && unzip -d /opt /tmp/studio.zip \
    && rm /tmp/studio.zip

USER developer

CMD /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
```

Let me know if you have any further questions and I will do my best to answer them.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, joelnb, it's now clarified to me. I'm gonna test these changes and give you a feedback.

Comment: Once the issue of running a GUI during a docker build runs away from theme of main question of this topic, I'm gonna open another question.

Comment: Good call. Could you please comment here with a link though? I probably don't know enough to answer that but I would be interested to see an answer if there is one.

Comment: Sure yes, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36947781/running-gui-during-docker-build/36948824#36948824