# Running GUI during docker build

Tags: docker

From [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36928740/installing-openjdk-in-docker-removes-basic-linux-commads/36934206) about docker, I've thought about a new question: is it possible to run a "gui app", and interact with it, during a docker mean?

The context is: in Dockerfile, you define a RUN command to exec a GUI installer (in that question, it was qt-android), and then, when you build image, it does not work, because it can't connect to display.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. On Linux there are various techniques (mostly involving binding / forwarding the X11 socket). Check out some of [Jessie Frazelle's Dockerfiles](https://github.com/jfrazelle/dockerfiles).

Answer (score 0):

Hm, thanks man... I see now that my question somewhat gone differently that I thought, but let's go: in fact, it's possible run containers with GUI, but, during **build process** of a container image, is it possible to run a GUI app and interact with (for, as an example, a GUI installer of an app)...